# High Quality Images Rendering in Chrome

Tags: image, css, google-chrome, matrix, 3d

There is a problem with **High Quality Images Rendering in Chrome** using **matrix3d**.

I've attached the link to the example where is reproduced this problem:
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7abx92ke/1/)

Make zoom out to see all high quality images on the page and you will see that some of these images are displayed partially.

If you change

```
transform: matrix3d(0.5,0,0.00,0,0.00,0.5,0.00,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1);
```

to

```
transform: matrix(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0);
```

it will work in **Chrome**.

In addition to it, this example is working in **Firefox** and in **Internet Explorer**.

How can I fix this problem with **matrix3d**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug in Chrome.
It was opened bug here:
[bugs.chromium.org/xxx](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=606287)

In addition to it, this problem is reproduced because of 100% GPU memory usage.